# Can SoundManager2 use Flash as a backup for the same sounds if HTML5 is not available?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, soundmanager2

SoundManager2 seems awesome, but the main reason I'm looking to use something other than solo HTML5 is compatibility. What I would like SM2 to do is use HTML5 audio if available, and fall-back to Flash otherwise (for the same sounds). It seems like it should be able to do it, but I haven't yet figured out how.

For example, I'd create a sound called "moo" and link to the sound file. SM2 would then see if it can play that sound using HTML5. If not, it would load Flash to play the sound instead. From the perspective of my app, I should only request the playback of "moo" and SM2 would take care of making sure it plays.

I suspect it may be necessary for me to generate the audio clips in more than one format (possibly .ogg for HTML5 and MP3 for Flash?). I can do that if needed.

Alternatively, I could have my own JavaScript code to detect if the browser will be able to play sounds using HTML5 and pass a different configuration to SM2, but I'd prefer a cleaner way.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Have you looked into jplayer? It does just that but requires jQuery. We use it for media playback cross browser

Comment: That answers my question. If you could post that as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org).

It's what we use for cross-platform support.  The documentation can be a little sparse at times, but it's rather useful.

Answer (score 2):

yes, SM2 uses a Flash fallback:

> Using HTML5 and Flash, SoundManager 2 provides reliable cross-platform
>   audio under a single JavaScript API

both SM2 and jPlayer will give you want you want, it just boils down to API preference.

generally, i'd choose jPlayer if cross-browser compatibility is crucial to you - SM2 is comparatively new to the world of HTML5 audio.. choose SM2 if you're happy using Flash and want more advanced features like access to the raw samples of the audio (to build a level meter or visualisation).

Comment: Please elaborate on the SM2 approach. It sounds like it will do what I'm looking for, but how? I'd need to specify links to both an .mp3 and an .ogg for each sound (since not everything can play mp3 or ogg) and choose either HTML5 or Flash as a default. All I was able to get so far is either Flash or HTML5, and with no fallback (e.g. it would fail to play on an HTML5 browser that doesn't have Flash)

Comment: have you looked into this feature?  http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/#soundmanager-usehtml5audio

Comment: I think that works if the format specified is supported by both Flash and the browser. It seems to me that to get great compatibility, SM2 will have to allow specifying multiple audio files in different formats for the same sound, so that it can keep testing until it finds one that works in either HTML5 or Flash. Am I right?

Comment: yes, that's right.. but it's the same with jPlayer - you supply multiple formats to increase compatibility.. generally, i'd choose jPlayer if cross-browser compatibility is crucial to you - SM2 is relatively new to the world of HTML5 audio.. choose SM2 if you're happy using Flash and want more advanced features like access to the raw samples of the audio (to build a level meter or visualisation)..